# TFS Build Nuget Package Error

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are setting up a new TFS build server and have created "New Build Definition" through visual studio 2013. The project is built based on ASP.NET MVC framework and it compiles without any error, but when we run the build definition it fails and getting the below mentioned error. ( just sample error message, it fails for all the nuget packages)

```
....Unable to find version '6.1.3' of package 'EntityFramework'.
.....Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client'.
....Unable to find version '3.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor'.
.....Unable to find version '5.2.3' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc'.
```

We haven't installed visual studio or nuget manager in the build server. Do we have to install visual studio in the build server? or anything needs to be done on the web project? The Build server has internet access.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which version of tfs?

Answer (score 1):

A build agent should be more or less identical to a developer's workstation. That includes having an appropriate version of Visual Studio installed.

You **can** get builds running without installing Visual Studio, but it involves jumping through a lot of hoops. There is no additional licensing cost for installing VS on a build server, if I recall correctly. So save yourself a lot of pain and install Visual Studio.